# Can't create Portal User. REQUIRED_FIELD_MISSING, Required fields are missing: [Profile]: [Profile]

Tags: salesforce, apex

I am trying to create Portal User from Community public page using this code:

```
this.userVar = new User(
                Alias = (this.contactVar.FirstName + this.contactVar.LastName).toLowerCase(),
                Email = this.contactVar.Email,
                FirstName = this.contactVar.FirstName,
                LastName = this.contactVar.LastName,
                EmailEncodingKey = 'UTF-8',
                LanguageLocaleKey = 'en_US',
                LocaleSidKey = 'en_AU',
                Country = 'Australia',
                ProfileId = assistanceHubProfile.Id,
                IsActive = true,
                TimeZoneSidKey = 'Australia/Sydney',
                Username = this.contactVar.Email,
                ContactId = this.contactVar.Id
            );
            System.debug(this.userVar);
            insert this.userVar;
```

but I have this error:

```
Insert failed. First exception on row 0; first error: REQUIRED_FIELD_MISSING, Required fields are missing: [Profile]: [Profile]
```

System debug before insert:

```
User:{Alias=tedsttestte, Email=test@test.com, FirstName=Tedst, LastName=Testte, EmailEncodingKey=UTF-8, LanguageLocaleKey=en_US, LocaleSidKey=en_AU, Country=Australia, ProfileId=00e920000002Ag1AAE, IsActive=true, TimeZoneSidKey=Australia/Sydney, Username=test@test.com, ContactId=00392000003RLeXAAW}
```

As you can see ProfileId is populated. I can't understand why this error is occurred.

There are no triggers and triggered-flow for User SObject

Comment: What is it running as? Guest user and some self registration page? 1 community user promoting another contact to community user? It's a long standing issue, check https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/a/284739/799 out. You may have to mark the profile for self registering or experiment with things like `@future`

Answer (score 0):

It was because I didn't use `without sharing` key words in apex class definition. In my case apex class will use `with sharing` settings by default.